# Google Doc referencing another sheet

Tags: reference, google-sheets, google-docs

After speaking to Google Enterprise Support they suggested I create a post on Stackoverflow.

I have a Google Doc sheet with a list of stores (sheet A) and I'm trying to reference another sheet (sheet B) to VOID specific stores.

What I'm going to accomplish is if a store name on the void sheet is entered into sheet A it will automatically convert the store name to VOID.

Google support believes an IF statement would be the beginning to the solution, they weren't able to help beyond this.

For anyone's time that comes up with a solution, I'd be happy to buy you a couple Starbucks coffees.  Your support means a lot.

Answer (score 0):

make it simple using [Google Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets). ([Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles?csw=1))

To edit scripts do: Tools -> Script Editor

and in the current add this function

**EDIT:**

Well, you need to make a trigger. In this case will be when the current sheet is edited

Here is the javascript

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // get actual spreadsheet
  var actual = event.source.getActiveSheet();

  // Returns the active cell
  var cellSheet1 = actual.getActiveCell();

  // get actual range
  var range = event.source.getActiveRange();

  // get active spreadsheet
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get sheets
  var sheet_two = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  range.copyValuesToRange(sheet_two, range.getColumn(), range.getColumn(), range.getRow(), range.getRow());

  // get cell from sheet2
  var cell = sheet_two.getRange(range.getValue());
  cell.setValue(cellSheet1.getValue());

  // display log
  Logger.log(cellSheet1.getValue());
}
```

if you want to test it you can check [my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ap6NqiXhRdBedDdtaHh6c2VGQWQwemZBa1RMVS13ZlE&usp=drive_web#gid=0), there you can check that all data thats is inserted in sheet1 will be copied to sheet2

Comment: Pablo would you be available to put together a script if compensated?